# WSO2 ESB: HTTPS API

Tags: api, ssl, https, wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to enable HTTPS protocol for an API on the WSO2 ESB?

> **https**://localhost:8280/api/mySslApi

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the HTTPS endpoint of the API and it's enabled by default. Note that HTTPS port is 8243 not 8280.

```
https://localhost:8243/api/mySslApi
```

Comment: Hi, its not working for me. When i invoke my api with https protocol and 8243 port, i could not receive any response. Can you advise please?

Answer (score 1):

By default it is already enabled that way, if you follow axi2.xml config ,you will find below details,

1.for Http

```
 <transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
    <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
    <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
    <!--<parameter name="priorityConfigFile" locked="false">location of priority configuration file</parameter>-->
</transportReceiver>
```

2.for Https

```
<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="false">8243</parameter>
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="HttpsProtocols">TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In WSO2 ESB, when we want to secure a REST API, we can simply make it available via HTTPS like bellow.

```
 <resource uri-template="/view/{symbol}" methods="GET" protocol="https">
```

And let the security handlers validate the credentials.

```
   <handlers>
       <handler class="org.wso2.rest.BasicAuthHandler"/>
    </handlers>
```

For detail information : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Securing+APIs

Answer (score -1):

We currently support BasicAuth/usernametoken secured endpoints via the publisher..You may need to edit the axis2.xml for "HostnameVerifier" parameter in caseof handshake errors..Check the following link for further details.
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM131/Adding+an+API

Comment: I'm using WSO2 ESB, so I need a solution involving the ESB product. The link gives an explanation about API Manager instead. Is the same thing possible for ESB?